# What does the player role 'Captain' in FIFA 14 do?

Tags: fifa-14

When you go into team management, you can select player roles. Most of them make sense, like who is taking the corners, free kicks and penalties. But what exactly does the captain do in FIFA 14? **Does the selection of captain influence the gameplay**, or is this just who is going to wear the armband and get mentioned by the commentators when scoring a goal?

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_%28association_football%29), the captains only two responsibilities that I believe could be in the game are just graphical things: to hoist up cup if you win a tournament and to participate in the coin toss at the beginning of the match. Both do not hold any significance for gameplay of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it won't change gameplay in any way. Basically, Captains in FIFA only exist so that it's close to real football.

And while in real football, the captain is usually a player with a good tactical awareness, and someone who can lead the team, to whom everybody sort of listens, in FIFA it only comes down to preference, nothing more.

I normally choose a player who seems most like a captain to me. In Career Mode (I manage Atlético Madrid) my captain is David Luiz, which is simply because I noticed that in games he is often a driving force, providing assists to strikers and running into free space. Lately though, I have been experimenting with giving the armband to other players, like Javi Martínez in Midfield, or Hulk as a Striker. And it didn't make one tad bit of difference! So as I said before, you can pick whoever player you think looks best shaking hands with the opposite captain or whatever :) It really doesn't influence gameplay at all.

Comment: IIRC years ago the captain was the only player allowed to speak and complain with the referee. But in Fifa the only difference is that the captain is the player that lift the cup when celebrating a competition, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can become a captain in fifa 14.

To become captain in any team...(100% working trick)

1. First regenerate your game using Creation master 14.
2. Open your game start a new career,and save the game and close it.
3. Go to your main game folder(fifa 14>game>data>db), open the text file(.xml may be) with notepad.
4. In notepad, go to edit bar, then select find, and type, `FVzk` (means find FVzk in the file using notepad).
5. Replace every `FVzk` with `hPku`.
6. Open creation master again, in the open bar look for select all and select your game.
7. This time do not regenerate or save but directly exit.
8. Open your game, load career, now you will become captain of both club and nation.

Comment: This seems to miss the point, question is asking "What does the captain do?" not "How do I make someone captain".