# How to become captain of your club?

Tags: fifa-14

Its been my 9th season as the best player of my club. But still I could not be a captain of my club.
Could anybody help me to achieve that? Any tip or trick would help.

Answer (score 2):

From [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/170501/163757) asked here, it's denoted that in that Player Roles sections in Team Management you can select captain as a role:

> When you go into team management, you can select player roles. Most of them make sense, like who is taking the corners, free kicks and penalties. But what exactly does the captain do in FIFA 14?

However, this kind of sounds like a different game mode (something called FUT from what I am reading?), and I'm not sure if it will work within clubs or player career mode.

Besides that, I want to say that it is not possible.  I've found multiple sources stating this.  Whether or not they are credible is up to you, but seeing as I've found a few, they back one another up.  A list of them:

- [EA Forum](https://fifaforums.easports.com/en/discussion/33162/can-you-become-captain-in-player-career-mode)
- [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/FifaCareers/comments/2jbaca/captain_in_pro_career_mode/)
- [Soccer Gaming](http://www.soccergaming.com/showthread.php?t=190267)

One place that says you can is [Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140624230740AAPs0CJ). Someone answered saying:

> In Fifa 14 a player becomes the captain by being a valued player, and also by having the highest overall grading in the club.

I also found [one more site](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/716877-fifa-14/69794578) that seems to agree with this:

> Just gotta play better. have a high end of match ranking and you'll become one soon enough.

Do you have the highest grade in the club? You said that your player is the best, so I'm assuming you have the highest grade already, but maybe double check.

One other thing you can try on PC is the [second answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/211683/163757) from the question linked above.  You have to modify an XML file to change who is captain.  If you try this, be careful of what you modify! I would make a backup copy first then try this. Here are the steps from the answer:

> 1. First regenerate your game using Creation master 14.
> 2. Open your game start a new career,and save the game and close it.
> 3. Go to your main game folder(fifa 14>game>data>db), open the text file(.xml may be) with notepad.
> 4. In notepad, go to edit bar, then select find, and type, `FVzk` (means find FVzk in the file using notepad).
> 5. Replace every `FVzk` with `hPku`.
> 6. Open creation master again, in the open bar look for select all and select your game.
> 7. This time do not regenerate or save but directly exit.
> 8. Open your game, load career, now you will become captain of both club and nation.