# Captain in player career

Tags: fifa-18

What are the chances and criteria of becoming team Captain in your player career?

I've been researching this topic for quite a while now and found no decent answer. [This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/295696/how-to-become-captain-of-your-club) looked promising at first, but the answer is not helpful and about a different game, so it's probably not applicable anyway. Also I'm playing FIFA on the PS4 and not on PC.

Some quick facts:

- Valued player - I guess a rating of 90+ with the rest of the team around 70 is enough
- Started career with the club and still there since 4 seasons
- Got promoted from 3rd to 1st league
- Trainer rating of 9.x - 10.0 overall
- Striker
- Player of the month multiple times
- Most goals and assists

Comment: What about the leadership rating ? I thought that mattered the most.

Comment: @VishaalShankar feel free to post an answer if you know what you need to become captain :)